# Clustered samples in case control studies

Tags: case-control-study, cluster-sample

In health systems research, in which data is usually gathered from practices or clinics, why are case control studies often designed without correction for design effect?

Comment: If your question is about _clustered sample_ use the corresponding tag, not tag `clustering` (which pertains to cluster analysis).